# FullCalendar v4 compare event date

Tags: javascript, date, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

i have problem with comparing two dates for FullCalendar v4:

First i set today date:

```
var today_a = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
```

next i try co compare this date with event start date [collected from Django view] using template language, to change its color, like this:

```
events: [
    {% for event in main_events %}
        {
            color: {% if sub_event.start_date|date:"Y-m-d" < today_a %}'green'{%else%}'SkyBlue'{%endif%},
        },
    {% endfor %}
],
```

That is not working but if i set static date instead of today_a then all is working as expected:

```
color: {% if sub_event.start_date|date:"Y-m-d" < '2019-10-30' %}'green'{%else%}'SkyBlue'{%endif%},
```

Variable today_a is a string. How to put this variable for compare to work?

Comment: What programming language is the code between the `{%` brackets? I don't immediately recognise it. Is it some framework-specific sub-species of PHP or JavaScript? Or something else? It would help you if you add a tag for it, then people with relevant expertise will see your question.

Comment: I would guess that your problem occurs because `today_a` is a JavaScript variable and this other code is either not JavaScript, and/or is executed in a different context. You generally cannot simply share variables between different programming languages. You also didn't say exactly what goes wrong, but I guess it gives you some sort of error? It would make sense to mention it. But anyway if you want to use today's date there, just declare that within your `{%` block in the correct programming language. There must be an equivalent in that language

Comment: `new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10)` does not reliably return the local date for "today" where the timezone offset is something other than +0.

Comment: @ADyson You right i make some updates in question. I think that today_a is not visible inside events bracket

Comment: @ZarakiKenpachi if you found the solution, you should write it as an answer below, not inside the question. Then people can vote on it, and it will appear in search results as well for others to see. The solution is separate, it is not part of the problem! But I still think you could just use the equivalent code in whatever language is between the `{% %}` blocks (is it python??) to get the current date, and it would be more efficient. And as RobG points out, `toISOString().slice(0, 10)` is not always reliable either.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to [ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson) sugestions i have managed this by using eventRender:

```
  eventRender: function(info) {
       if (info.event.start.toISOString().slice(0, 10) < today_a) {
         info.el.style.backgroundImage = 'linear-gradient(to right, red, yellow)';
       }
```

Thank You All for help :)

Comment: This basically works, but to anyone reading, bear in mind the warning in RobG's comment above that `toISOString().slice(0, 10)` may not be reliable in all situations.